# A purely discontinuous process with jumps +1 is Poisson.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am reading Bass's book on Stochastic processes on my own. I cam across the following exercise in Chapter 17.

> 17.8 Suppose $X_t$ is an increasing process with paths that are right continuous with left limits, $X_0=0$ a.s., $X$ is purely discontinuous, and all jumps are of size $+1$ only. Suppose that $\lim\limits_{t\to \infty}X_t=\infty,$ a.s. Then prove that $X_t$ is a time change Poisson process.

I am feeling uneasy about this exercise. Suppose, I have a (deterministic) process which jumps at every integer, and jump sizes are one. Then this process satisfies all the hypothesis in the question, but how can it be a Poisson process? Jumps in Poisson process  are completely unpredictable. I can not wrap my head around this problem.

I would appreciate if somebody can elucidate the issue and explain to me what I am missing?

Comment: Looking at this (I don't have further context at my disposal) I feel uneasy too. A homogeneous Poisson process arises if the start with iid increments with exponential distribution. But we can start easily with increments that have a different distribution. Just like you I don't see where conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: You ask "how can it be a Poisson process?".. In fact you are not asked to prove it's a Poisson process, but rather the time change of a Poisson process...

Comment: @Tom I know it asks only to prove that it is a time changed Poisson process. Any lead on that? Can you help me with how to prove it is a time changed Poisson process?

Comment: I think you re right.. What you're asked to prove seems false.. I think you need the compensator of $X$ to be continuous or maybe even absolutely continuous.. I am not sure about the details which I ll try to fill in as soon as I have time if nobody else does..

Comment: Your counterexample is correct and the claim is false. Further assumptions on $X_t$ are needed in order for it to be a time changed Poisson process.